# maps js api v3 returns ZERO_RESULTS for known good addresses

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

Recently I've noticed (after users told me) that some addresses fail to geocode using the js-api. The affected addresses all geocoded successfully earlier. According to users this happens for like 2 or 3 weeks now. At first I thought it would be a bug on my side. But while debugging I've tried the affected addresses in the example at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple and it fails there, too.

So I assume it's a bug in the api, but I wanted to ask here before opening an issue since it's Monday and well possible I'm just stupid right now ^^. Esp. since I can't recognize a clear pattern in it.

'Known good' but affected addresses:

- Friedrich-Wilhelm-Str. 3, 47051 Duisburg, Deutschland
- Friedrich-Wilhelm-Platz 5, 47051 Duisburg, Deutschland

  - this one partially work - if house number is omitted (Friedrich-Wilhelm-Platz, 47051 Duisburg, Deutschland)

Trying to get more, based on user feedback it happens on "many" address containing a dash. Yet they couldn't provide more examples so far. Could be caused by the length I thought, but other longer ones work fine. The dashes also can't be the issue, I've found dashed addresses (Pastor-Bölitz-Str. 31, 48463 Wesel, Deutschland) that still work.

No clue how to continue now, anyone got an idea to workaround or should I open an issue on https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list ? Or have I just missed some required change that isn't reflected in that example yet?

### Edit #1 / Code & more data:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=removed&sensor=false&language=de-DE"></script>
```

js (where var address is like the listed ones):

```
mcgeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
mcgeocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      gResults = results[0];
      if(gResults.types[0] == "street_address") {
        // actual doing stuff removed for simplification
      } 
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
});
```

But I don't think it's caused by the actual code, since the given addresses also fail in the example code / online example.

So far all addresses I've found to be affected contain "rich" somewhere in the street part. I haven't found a single one without "rich", but then again some that contains it and work anyway...

More "worked earlier but broken now" addresses:

- Kaiser-Friedrich-Ring 36, 65185 Wiesbaden, Deutschland

Matching the above "rich" pattern, but still working:

- Carl-Friederichs-Straße 18, 42853 Remscheid, Deutschland
- Eugen-Richter-Str. 86, 58089 Hagen, Deutschland
- Friedrichstraße 143, 71638 Ludwigsburg, Deutschland
- Ludwig-Richter-Weg 14, 70794 Filderstadt, Deutschland
- Friedrichstraße 7, 74080 Heilbronn, Deutschland

### Edit #2 / Note on listed addresses

I've just noticed that some of the test addresses from "Edit #1" were valid ZERO_RESULTS, should have double checked before - my bad, removed them. The remaining not working ones, should not return ZERO_RESULTS for sure and worked earlier.

### Edit #3 / More affected data

Christian-Ritter-von-Langheinrich-Straße 1, 95448 Bayreuth, Deutschland (thought I don't know if this one ever worked)

### Edit #4 / Another example, this one even fails on Maps itself

Kaiser-Friedrich-Straße 226, 47167 Duisburg, Deutschland

For this I'm also not sure if it ever worked, but for sure this address is correct.

You can view the area on Maps (google.de/maps/@51.5084844,6.7841918,20.25z), but can't search (s30.postimg.org/j5vyf73sx/kfs_3.png) nor geocode that address (s1.postimg.org/l0s5c9gv3/kfs_2.png).

Funny thing is, if you click the house the appearing popup correctly tells the housenumber (s18.postimg.org/jvjnvxsu1/kfs_4.png). I've shown that screenshot to the reporting user, and he confirmed that's the correct house. The building looks a bit dated, so it can't be "to new to be known yet".
 [Sorry for the messy links, reputation limit ;)]

If you write "Kaiser-Friedrich-Str 226, 47167 Duisburg" instead, Maps can find it halfway - view get centered approx. on the street, but wrong number - guess some partial match based on zip. Written like that the geocode request for it still fails with ZERO_RESULTS.

I think there is something messed up with the data for some regions, at least for Duisburg. Gonna open an issue for it later.

Comment: Where is your code? What version of the API are you using? etc. etc.

Comment: Like the title says, v3. 

Code can't matter since those addresses also fail on the example given in docs.  Anyway, here it is...

edit: ups, limit hit - gonna add to the post

Added more info affected addresses to the post.

Comment: Looks like a data-defect, I would send a bug-report

Comment: `Kaiser-Friedrich-Ring 36, 65185 Wiesbaden, Deutschland` looks like a "place", not an address (at least from the result I see on Google Maps)

Comment: It's a valid address, I'm not sure what you mean?